# Variable numbers of parameters in a SqlClr UDF or Stored Proc

Tags: sql-clr, extended-stored-procedure

Lets say I have the following signature for a CLR Stored Proc or UDF:

```cs
[Public]
public static void RaisError(
    string message, 
    short severity, 
    short state, 
    params object[] args)
```

The generated DDL is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RaisError]
    @message [nvarchar](4000), 
    @severity [smallint],
    @state [smallint],
    @args /* Error: Unsupported type. */
AS EXTERNAL NAME [SqlSaturdayClr].[StoredProcedures].[RaisError];
```

I can manually write DDL to reference the stored procedure with any number of variables, defaulting them all to null. However, is there a T-SQL way to say "this stored procedure has a variable number of arguments" in the same way as [`sp_executesql`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) does?

From [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8571/Writing-Extended-Stored-Procedures-in-C) it seems that extended stored procs intrinsically have a varariable number of variables and you have to enforce variable length in the code. Is my only option to use an extended stored procedure?

Comment: This seems like an ideal use case for table-valued parameters.

Comment: @AaronBertrand table value parameters would work, but thats a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Actually, I think I could make that pretty elegant.

Answer (score 2):

> *I can manually write DDL to reference the stored procedure with any number of variables, defaulting them all to null. However, is there a T-SQL way to say "this stored procedure has a variable number of arguments" in the same way as sp_executesql does?*

No, there's no built-in way to do this.

> *Is my only option to use an extended stored procedure?*

You should avoid writing an extended stored procedure, since these have been [deprecated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175200.aspx) since SQL Server 2005 and generally cause more problems than they solve. There is no really good way to simulate the optional parameter behaviour of things like `sp_executesql` with a `SQLCLR` procedure or function.

Various workarounds can be suitable depending on the situation. The most often recommended is a `T-SQL` procedure or function wrapper, though I have also seen people experiment with passing a `SQLCLR` type (containing an array of values, for example) as well. The T-SQL equivalent to that would be a table-valued parameter.

Comment: I know extended stored procs are deprecated, and I'm sure I'll discover they're a pain to build and deploy. However, it seems that in the end they would produce the most succinct syntax.

Comment: @Justin what's the advantage of slightly more succinct syntax that you may have to re-write soon?